# Only put random number in list if doesn't exist in a different list

Tags: c#, list, loops, hashset

I have another list named `lRVars`

I am trying to generate another list with a hashSet generated from a loop as follows, however, I need to make sure that the number doesn't already exist in the above list:

```
List<int> lCVars = new List<int>();
HashSet<int> hCVars = new HashSet<int>();

        while (hCVars.Count < randCVarsCount)         
        {
            hCVars.Add(rnd.Next(1, 11));

        }  

        lColVars = hsColVars.ToList();
```

So in the above loop, I need to check if the `rnd.Next` already exists in the list being compared and can't figure out the syntax.

An extra eye would be great.

Comment: You don't need to do that for `HashSet`s. They are unique collections by design. If you mean if it doesn't exist in `lCVars`, then you do `var num = rnd.Next(1,11); if (!lCVars.Contains(num)) hCVars.Add(num);`

Comment: @Rob OP wants to check if value being added to HashSet `hCVars` is not present in another list `lRVars`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need a temporary variable for the random number and use that to check it already exists.

You *could* add an `else` clause and only add it to the `HashSet` if it isn't already in there, but the `Add` method does that (i.e. `hs.Add(8); hs.Add(8); //hs will only have count of 1`)

```
List<int> lCVars = new List<int>();
HashSet<int> hCVars = new HashSet<int>();
var rnd = new Random();
var randCVarsCount = 5;
while (hCVars.Count < randCVarsCount)
{
    var num = rnd.Next(1, 11);
    if (hCVars.Contains(num))
        Console.WriteLine("already in there");
    hCVars.Add(num);
}

lColVars = hsColVars.ToList();
```

Comment: you're still adding it

Comment: if (hCVars.Contains(num))
  {      Console.WriteLine("already in there");}
 else{   hCVars.Add(num);}

Comment: accepted answer....but @MCain comment above is what that line should be edited to to make it work.   Thanks though....the point is what mattered ;)

Comment: You don't need the contains check, `Add` returns a bool if the item was there or not. `if(!hCVars.Add(num)) { Console.WriteLine("already in there"); }`

Answer (score 1):

Since the `HashSet.ToList()` method returns a new `List`, converting the `HashSet` into a `List` should guarantee the uniqueness of the values within your `List` object.

The source code for the `ToList` method showing this is below:

```
public static List<TSource> ToList<TSource> (this IEnumerable<TSource> source)
{
    Check.Source (source);
    return new List<TSource> (source);
}
```

In your app, you just need your own temporary variable to store the random number you wish to check. The sample program below shows the two ways of doing it.

```
#define UNCONDITIONAL

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;


namespace StackOverflow
{
    class MainClass
    {
        public static void Main (string[] args)
        {
            HashSet<int> hash = new HashSet<int>();
            Random rnd = new Random();

#if(UNCONDITIONAL)
            Console.WriteLine("Adding unconditionally...");
#else
            Console.WriteLine("Adding after checks...");
#endif

            while(hash.Count < 5)
            {
                int rv = rnd.Next (1, 11);
#if(UNCONDITIONAL)
                hash.Add (rv);
#else
                if(hash.Contains(rv))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine ("Duplicate skipped");
                }
                else
                {
                    hash.Add (rv);
                }
#endif
            }

            List<int> list = hash.ToList ();  // ToList() gives back a new instance
            foreach(var e in list)
            {
                Console.WriteLine (e);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**NOTE:** The `UNCONDITIONAL` symbol is simply to let you play around with an example more easily. You can comment it out to see both behaviors.

Sample output with symbol defined:

```
Adding unconditionally...
5
10
2
6
3
```

Sample output with symbol commented out:

```
Adding after checks...
Duplicate skipped
7
3
4
2
10
```